# Stop new @comment for comment form displaying on show page in @comments - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, comments, polymorphic-associations

Hi I am quite new to Rails and am just setting up comments for my Shop_Profile model. I am using the acts_as_commentable gem to allow for polymorphic comments. I am allowing comments on the profile Show page so am displaying the list of comments and the new comment form on the same page.

My Show Action in the ShopProfilesController looks like this:

```
def show
    @comments = @shop_profile.comments
    @comment = @shop_profile.comments.new
  end
```

And I am rendering the comment form and comments in the show view with:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'comments/form' %>
<% end %>

<%= render @comments %>
```

My Create action on my comment controller is:

```
def create
    @comment = @user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @commentable = Comment.find_commentable(params[:comment][:commentable_type], params[:comment][:commentable_id])

    if @comment.save
      redirect_to @commentable
    end
  end
```

and my _comment partial is:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= comment.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Comment:</strong>
  <%= comment.comment %>
</p>

<p>
  <small>By:</small>
  <%= comment.user.username %>
</p>
```

The new @comment for the form keeps getting included in the @comments and is thus causing an error **"undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass"** because the new @commentn has no **user_id**.
How can I display my @comments without including this new @comment for the form_for?

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's not clear why your `@comments` variable is getting polluted with unsaved data, that's your real issue here.  Don't hide it by making bad data acceptable in the listing.  Is `user_id` required?  Are you sure there is no record saved in the database on `Tattoos` that has a null `user_id`?

Comment: sorry I just corrected the '@comment' variable to the correct '@shop_profile', I think that it is the new '@comment' variable that is causing the problem, there are no comments saved in the database with a null user_id

Comment: Ok, makes sense now, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately (in this case) `new`/`build` adds the built object to the association's collection.  So you'll need to declare your intent that you **only** want items stored in the database for the `@comments` collection.

You have two options I know of off the top of my head:

```
def show
  @comment = @shop_profile.comments.new
  @comments = @shop_profile.comments(true)
end
```

This forces the `@comments` to be loaded cleanly, so it will only contain the original list.  Unfortunately you're hitting the database twice for the same list, that's silly.

Even better, I think, for this would be to do:

```
def show
  @comments = @shop_profile.comments.to_a
  @comment = @shop_profile.comments.new
end
```

So now you detatch the `@comments` collection from the active record association by making it an array, so the `new` call later on won't modify anything you still are holding on to.

Comment: Thanks this is a great solution its super simple with a great explanation. Are there any drawbacks to using the .to_a solution?

Comment: Nah shouldn't be, unless you were using ActiveRecord association methods later on in your views.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an additional comment in your collection, and that new comment doesn't have an associated user yet, and isn't saved in the database yet.

If you want the new comment to be skipped entirely, you can do this:

```
<%= render @comments.reject{|c| c == @comment } %>
```

If you want the new comment to show up, but skip the "By" section, you can do this:

```
<% if comment != @comment %>
  <p>
    <small>By:</small>
    <%= comment.user.username %>
 </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice. This would work but there should never be a case where a comment has user_id: nil in the database so I thought there might be a cleaner way of stopping the new comment for the form getting included in the comments.all and causing the error

Comment: I see. Yes, I'll add more.